# Sum of Expectations of RVs with different distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I came across this question:

Let $Y=\sum^{N}_{i=1}X_i$.
Suppose $X_1, X_2,...$ are independently distributed with different distributions (e.g., $X_i \sim N(\mu, i+1))$, find $E[Y] $ and prove it.

I understand that suppose if all $X_i$ are in fact i.i.d., the sum of the expectations would very simply be $NE[X_1]$. However, in this case the distributions are not the same. Assuming that they all are indeed normally distributed with a mean of $\mu$, my understanding is that it would simply be $N\mu$. However, what if they are not all normally distributed? Would it simply be $E[X_1] + E[X_2] + ... + E[X_N]$? Is there any more reigorous proof to it?

In addition, what if they are not independent? It is my understanding that the expectation, as a linear summation, is regardless of whether the r.v.s are independent. Is this so?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @MatthewH. Not all random variables have densities.

Comment: Expectation of a sum is the sum of the expectations ALWAYS (assuming, of course, that expectations exist and are finite). Nothing to do with independence or particular distributions.

Comment: There is no scope for bringing in $dV_N$ when densities don't exist. Please do not make comments that  mislead OP.